# Returning wrong count in a recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I am am not returning the correct number when trying to search recursively. I am using this to traverse a queue implemented with a singly linked list and return the index that the item is at so I can determine how many times I need to dequeue() to get to that item.

```
public int search(E item) {
    return recSearch(item, head);
}

public int recSearch(E item, Node node){
    if (head == null){
        return -1;
    }else if (node.data.equals(item)){
        return searchCnt;
    }else{
        searchCnt++;
        return recSearch(item, node.next);
    }
}
```

I feel like it should be counting correctly because it's going to have to count every time it fails to meet the if and else if conditions, but am I not incrementing in the right place? Or am I just way off entirely? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where is `searchCnt` defined?

Comment: @Madbreaks It is defined as a class variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `searchCnt` to 0 inside `search()` just before calling `recSearch()`. Also, you need to test whether `node == null`, not `head == null`.

Alternatively, you could try this instead:

```
public int search(E item) {
    return recSearch(item, head, 0);
}

public int recSearch(E item, Node node, int index){
    if (node == null){
        return -1;
    }else if (node.data.equals(item)){
        return index;
    }else{
        return recSearch(item, node.next, index + 1);
    }
}
```

It eliminates the need for a class/instance variable.

Note that this does not allow `null` data at a node. To support `null` values, you would need another `if/else` branch right after the check for `node == null`:

```
}else if (item == null && node.data == null) {
    return index;
}
```

Comment: This makes total sense. Thank you my friend!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to pass your `searchCnt` var when recursing so that it gets updated properly.

```
public int search(E item) {
    return recSearch(item, head, 1);
}

public int recSearch(E item, Node node, int searchCnt){
    if (head == null){
        return -1;
    }else if (node.data.equals(item)){
        return searchCnt;
    }else{
        return recSearch(item, node.next, ++searchCnt);
    }
}
```

The `1` in the initial call assumes that, if you find your item in the first iteration of `recSearch`, that counts as one search (and `search` will return `1` in that case).